# How to sum column in datatable and check with DataTable.Compute?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `datatable` name `dt2` and I want to fetch sum of a column so I used `DataTable.Compute` and it worked fine. 
Now this is my line where I do the sum of column `Val(dt2.Compute("SUM(Price)", "[Vat_Per] =" & Val(RATE) & "and [Sale_Free] = 'R'"))`. 
Now I applied 2 filters here. Both work fine when there is data. But I get error when there is No data in datatable which fulfils `[Sale_Free] = 'R'`  
Error is `Argument expression cannot be converted to dbNull`

Checking for data like if `[Sale_Free] = 'R'` is available then SUM will be a long process for me.
Is there any way to make it 0 if it's Null or dbNull? `Val` seems not working...

Comment: `Val` is garbage in most cases. It should only be used to convert a `String` to a number and, even then, only when you specifically want to pick a number off the front of that text. For instance, if the user enters `"123o456"` by mistake instead of `"1230456"` and you passed that to `Val` then the result would be `123.0` and the code would just carry on executing and using the wrong data. Good code would actually detect that and inform the user of their mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is very simple: you are using `Val` and that is garbage. There are very few situations where using that `Val` function is a good idea and this is definitely not one of them.

The way that `DataTable.Compute` works, if there are no rows that match the filter then the result will be `DBNull.Value`. You can't pass that to `Val` and have anything useful happen and that's where your code is failing.

There's no use or justification for using `Val` anyway. That's for converting text to a number but you have no text to begin with, so what's the point? If there is data then the result will already be a number so there's no conversion to be done. If there is no data then you get `DBNull.Value` and you can just use zero explicitly.

```vb
Dim result = dt2.Compute("SUM(Price)", $"[Vat_Per] = {RATE} AND [Sale_Free] = 'R'")
Dim totalPrice = If(result Is DBNull.Value, 0.0, CDbl(result))
```

Comment: Okay, I truly say I have a misunderstanding about the `Val` keyword. I thought if the value in the variable is "" or nothing or null then Val will convert it to 0. I will take care of using val next time. And I am checking now. I'll mark as answer as soon as I make it run

Comment: @RitaShroff, the documentation says that an `ArgumentException` is thrown if *"`Expression` is an `Object` type expression that is not convertible to `String`"*. The conversion it's talking about is the use of `CType` and, if you test it, you'll see that you cannot use `CType` to convert a `DBNull` object to a `String` object.